# How to load an HTML file into a UIWebView with a Bookmark?

Tags: xcode, uiwebview, swift, nsurl, bookmarks

I am trying to load an HTML page into a UIWebView at a specific location in the page. I have set a bookmark in the page, and it properly loads from another page with the following anchor link:

```
<a href="cheddar#cabotClothBound">Cheddar Cheeses</a>
```

I have successfully loaded the page into the web view with the following code:

```
var f = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("cheddarCheese", ofType: "htm"))
paragraph.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: f))
```

I have several HTML bookmarks in the page, such as cabotClothBound, tillamook, and kerrygold.

How do I include the bookmark in the request? The following, seemingly obvious solution--simply include the hash in the `pathForResource` `name` parameter--fails:

```
var f = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("cheddarCheese#kerrygold", ofType: "htm"))
```

I can't seem to find a class that allows me to supply URL string parameters.

Perhaps as a broader question, how do I include URL parameters in an NSURL request. Thank you for your help.